# Can adjectives be placed before gerunds?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, gerunds

My question relates to the possibility of placing an adjective before a gerund if a sentence begins with the gerund.

For example, I'd like to prepare a list of my skills for a CV like 'Brief reading a text' (or the only option would be 'Reading a text briefly), 'Attentive proofreading' and so on.

Thanks in advance to native speakers for advice!

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a possible thing in case the gerund functions as a *noun*, not participle in that phrase. Looks like you need to add a preposition for that after 'reading' to link both 'nouns':

*Brief reading **of** a text.*